# Using resource bundle in Struts2 interceptors

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, web

Struts2 Actions normally extend `ActionSupport` class which implements of `TextProvider` interface and provides access to resource bundle files in a convenient way using `getText()` method.

I want to use resource bundle in Interceptors. I guess I have to copy `TextProvider` implementation and paste it in my interceptor.

I have already defined global recourse file in `struts.xml`

```
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="resources.global" />
```

And place `global.properties` in `resources` package.

It works fine in Action Classes

Is there any easier way to use resource bundle in interceptors?

Comment: and why you want to do that?Interceptor are not for action specific and they are not thread safe. i do not see any reason to do this.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Interceptor are not thread safe. I was not aware of it. This is really alarming. Thanks

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi What if you want to show an i18n error message to the user, and that message should be when the login interceptor sees you are not logged in anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your can use the `java.util.ResourceBundle` class.

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("my_resource_name", locale);
bundle.getString("resource_key");
```

Comment: I have a similar requirement.I am looking for a way I can pass  an array of arguments which can be replaced in the message text.Somewhat similar to methods of `DefaultTextProvider` class of Struts (xwork) framework.

Answer (score 4):

If your action is type of `ActionSupport` you can do as:

```
ActionSupport actionSupport = (ActionSupport)invocation.getAction();
actionSupport.getText("sample.key");
```

Comment: This is it. Then, from a POJO it is: `ActionSupport actionSupport = (ActionSupport) ActionContext.getContext().getActionInvocation().getAction();`